# How regenerate images with paperclip if field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

i need to regenrate paperclip attachments on products model, but only for the records that have a certain field empty.

I'm thinking to use lambda, but i can't resolv my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rails c production
@products = Product.where(:name => nil)
@products.each do |product|
  product.photo.process!
end
```

Comment: I had to use `reprocess!` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you field is, say, :name, you can do something like:

```
Product.where(:name => nil).each {|product| product.reprocess! }
```

Comment: thanks red, i try but the result was NoMethodError: undefined method `reprocess!'. The method reprocess it's included on paperclip ?